# Mistakenly put KitchenAid spiralizer in the dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

Mistakenly put KitchenAid spiralizer in the dishwasher, and now when you touch the main body the paint comes off on the hands.

Is there any way to remedy this, and was the spiralizer damaged by this mistake of putting it in the dishwasher?

Comment: I don't know that we can really help you with this but fortunately KitchenAid has a pretty good reputation for support. You can try contacting them at https://www.kitchenaid.com/resources/contact-us.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's really a product customer support question, not in the purview of cooks.

Comment: @Tetsujin the maintaining of kitchen equipment is on the whitelist of topics for the site.

Comment: @rumtscho - Maintenance perhaps, I'm not sure how we can help with something damaged by mis-use. Answer added with KitchenAid's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

From the KitchenAid instructions…

> **Is the KitchenAid® Spiralizer with Peel, Core and Slice attachment dishwasher safe?**
>
> The accessories (Fine Spiralizing Blade, Medium Spiralizing Blade, Large Core Slicing Blade, Small Core Slicing Blade, Peeling Blade) are dishwasher safe, top rack only. All blades are stainless steel. Clean the Spiralizer attachment main body by hand only. Wash with a soft, damp cloth. Dry thoroughly with a soft dry cloth. Do not wash in the dishwasher. Do not immerse in water.

Or from their web version - [How to Clean the KitchenAid Spiralizer Attachment and Accessories](https://producthelp.kitchenaid.com/Countertop_Appliances/Stand_Mixer_Attachments/Fresh_Prep/Spiralizer/Cleaning_-_Spiralizer_Atachment)

> IMPORTANT: To avoid damage, never wash or immerse the main body of the
> Spiralizer attachment in water or place in the dishwasher. The
> removable blades and accessories are dishwasher safe, top rack only.
>
> After using the Spiralizer, remove all blades and accessories. Wash
> the blades and accessory pieces by hand with a soft cloth, in warm,
> sudsy water; or, wash in the top rack of the dishwasher.
>
> Clean the main body of the Spiralizer attachment by hand only. Wash
> with a soft, damp cloth. Dry thoroughly with a soft dry cloth. Do not
> wash in the dishwasher. Do not immerse in water.

You'd have to [contact them](https://www.kitchenaid.com/resources/contact-us.html) & see if they might cover it under warranty.